# SQL Query Issue - Picking the minimum time when there is a maximum number

Tags: mysql, sql-server, case, case-when

SQL God...I need some help!

I have a data table that has a `route_complete_percentage` column and a `created_at` column.

I need two pieces of data:

1. the time stamp (within created_at column) when the `route_complete_percentage` is at its minimum but not zero
2. the time stamp (within created_at column) when the `route_complete_percentage` is at its maximum, it might be 100% or not, but when its at its highest.

Here is the kicker, there might be multiple time stamps for the highest route completion column.  For example,

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfxgz.png)

I have multiple values when the `route_completion_percentage` is at its maximum, but I need the minimum time stamp value.

Here is the query so far...but the two time stamps are the same.

```
SELECT 
A.fc,
A.plan_id,
A.route_id,
mintime.first_scan AS First_Batch_Scan,
min(route_complete_percentage),
maxtime.last_scan AS Last_Batch_Scan,
max(route_complete_percentage)

FROM
(SELECT 
    fc,
        plan_id,
        route_id,
        route_complete_percentage,
        CONCAT(plan_id, '-', route_id) AS JOINKEY
FROM
    houdini_ops.BATCHINATOR_SCAN_LOGS_V2
    WHERE
        fc <> ''
        AND order_id <> 'Can\'t find order'
        AND source = 'scan'
        AND created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 DAY)) A
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
    l.fc,
        l.route_id,
        l.plan_id,
        CONCAT(l.plan_id, '-', l.route_id) AS JOINKEY,
        CASE
            WHEN MIN(route_complete_percentage) THEN     CONVERT_TZ(l.created_at, 'UTC', s.time_zone)
        END AS first_scan
FROM
    houdini_ops.BATCHINATOR_SCAN_LOGS_V2 l
JOIN houdini_ops.O_SERVICE_AREA_ATTRIBUTES s ON l.fc = s.default_station_code
WHERE
        l.fc <> ''
        AND l.order_id <> 'Can\'t find order'
        AND l.source = 'scan'
        AND l.created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 DAY)
GROUP BY fc , plan_id , route_id) mintime ON A.JOINKEY = mintime.JOINKEY
    LEFT JOIN
(SELECT 
        l.fc,
        l.route_id,
        l.plan_id,
        CONCAT(l.plan_id, '-', l.route_id) AS JOINKEY,
        CASE
            WHEN MAX(route_complete_percentage) THEN     CONVERT_TZ(l.created_at, 'UTC', s.time_zone)
        END AS last_scan
FROM
    houdini_ops.BATCHINATOR_SCAN_LOGS_V2 l
JOIN houdini_ops.O_SERVICE_AREA_ATTRIBUTES s ON l.fc = s.default_station_code
WHERE
    l.fc <> ''
        AND l.order_id <> 'Can\'t find order'
        AND l.source = 'scan'
        AND l.created_at > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 3 DAY)
GROUP BY fc , plan_id , route_id) maxtime ON mintime.JOINKEY = maxtime.JOINKEY
GROUP BY fc , plan_id , route_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to meddle with the rest of your query. Here is something that will do what it sounds like you need. There's sample data included. -- I interpreted your blank values as nulls from your sample data.

Basically, what you are looking for is the Minimum created_at value, inside each of the route_complete_percentage groups. So I treated route_complete_percentage as a group identifier. But you only care about two of the groups, so I identify those groups first in the cte, and use them to filter the aggregate query.

```
    if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Data') is not null drop table #Data
go

create table #Data (
    route_complete_percentage int,
    created_at datetime
)

insert into #Data (route_complete_percentage, created_at)
    values 
        (0, '20170531 19:58'),
        (1, null),
        (2, null),
        (3, null),
        (4, null),
        (5, null),
        (6, null),
        (7, null),
        (80, null),
        (90, null),
        (100, '20170531 20:10'),
        (100, '20170531 20:12'),
        (100, '20170531 20:15')

;with cteMinMax(min_route_complete_percentage, max_route_complete_percentage) as (
    select
        min(route_complete_percentage),
        max(route_complete_percentage)
        from #Data D
            -- This ensures the condition that you don't get the timestamp for 0
            where D.route_complete_percentage > 0
)
select 
    route_complete_percentage, 
    min_created_at = min(created_at) 
    from #Data D
        join cteMinMax MM on D.route_complete_percentage in (MM.min_route_complete_percentage, MM.max_route_complete_percentage)
    group by route_complete_percentage
```